# Set Add / Edit / Display Form Views

Tags: 2010, list-view, data-view-web-part, form

I have looked a good bit and found several tutorials regarding how to set different views for the Add, Edit, and Display pages for my SharePoint 2010 form library.  Most of these mention using the Properties section in SPD to set the default view for a given page.

However, I cannot find this menu.  I have followed several tutorials to the same conclusion- this option doesn't seem to exist where the provided screenshots show it as existing. Does anyone know why this might be, or a way around it?

From the `Display.aspx` view, I have tried both Properties and Web Part Properties. I have also tried using Form Web Parts from the SharePoint ribbon, but it only shows 'Default Display Form' and 'Default Edit Form', with no way to change the default.

My form definitely has different views, as when I open a form in the browser, I can manually switch between them, but I still can't find a way to set defaults for individual tasks.

Answer (score 1):

Enable Content Type Management on List/Library Settings and then add different content types. Your forms will display fields based on the content type being used so if one content type has different fields than another, its forms will be different.